# Operators precedence in C Programming

Tags: c, operator-precedence

I am currently learning C Programming ( my first programming language ).
I am a little bit confused with the operators precedence.
Arithmetic operators precedence are as follows.

1. `*`
2. `/`
3. `%`
4. `+`
5. `-`

This is what is given in my book at least.
What i am confused is about how do i go solving expressions when it comes to my theory exams ?
I tried solving many expressing with the order given above but fail to get a correct answer.

Given the following definitions:

```
int a = 10, b = 20, c;
```

How would we solve this expression?

```
a + 4/6 * 6/2
```

This is an example in my book.

Comment: I've never heard of a \ operator. Are you sure you're learning C and not PHP?

Comment: @KerrekSB Damn! that was supposed to be `/`. Sorry, got confused. Have been studying from morning.

Comment: @912M0FR34K: Then it's time for a break! Programming is all about being pedantic and paying attention to detail. Take a walk and get a coffee, and it'll all be easier afterwards.

Comment: The statement of the operator precedence isn't correct. C uses the same precedence as mathematics. `* / %` have the same precedence in C and maths. `+ -` have the same precedence in C and maths. `* / %` have higher precedence than `+ -` in C and maths.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    a + 4/6 * 6/2 
 = 10 + 4/6 * 6/2
 = 10 + 0*6/2
 = 10 + 0/2
 = 10
```

Note that `4/6` evaluates to `0` as integer division is used.

Comment: Ah, that's what the OP meant by "solving an expression"!! :D +1

Answer (score 4):

The precedence of `/` and `*` is the same in C, just as it is in mathematics. The problem is that in mathematics the following expressions are equivalent, whereas in C they might not be:

```
(a/b) * (c/d)
(a/b*c) / d
```

These aren't equivalent in C because if `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` are integers, the `/` operator means integer division (it yields only the integral part of the result).

For example,

```
(7/2)*(4/5); //yelds 0, because 4/5 == 0
(7/2*4)/5; //yields 2
```

**A general good coding practice is being explicit about your intentions. In particular, parenthesize when in doubt. And sometimes even when you're not.**

Answer (score 2):

One safe real life solution is to always use parentheses ( )

Comment: That is when i am making program's. But i can just simply add parentheses in my exam paper right ?
Thanks for the suggestion though. Appreciated.

Comment: I would add them in an exam :)